# DB2 Merge Into Loop

Tags: loops, merge, db2

I am running into an issue where our log file is filling up before my merge can finish.  Is there a way i can iterate this merge into to merge 1000 at a time, commit, and start again?  Here is my merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO "SCHEMA"."PATIENT" AS DMT
USING "SCHEMA"."PATIENT_STAGE" AS Stage
ON ( DMT.MEMBER_ID = Stage.MEMBER_ID)
when matched then 
update set 
DMT.MEMBER_ID = Stage.MEMBER_ID, 
DMT.ADDRESS1 = Stage.ADDRESS1, 
DMT.ADDRESS2 = Stage.ADDRESS2,
DMT.BENEFIT_ID = Stage.BENEFIT_ID, 
DMT.CITY = Stage.CITY, 
DMT.STATE = Stage.STATE,
DMT.CLIENT_CLIENT_ID = Stage.CLIENT_CLIENT_ID,
DMT.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID = Stage.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID, 
DMT.CLIENT_GROUP_ID = Stage.CLIENT_GROUP_ID, 
DMT.DATE_OF_BIRTH = Stage.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
DMT.FIRST_NAME = Stage.FIRST_NAME, 
DMT.GENDER = Stage.GENDER, 
DMT.LAST_NAME = Stage.LAST_NAME,
DMT.MIDDLE_NAME = Stage.MIDDLE_NAME, 
DMT.PERSON_CODE = Stage.PERSON_CODE, 
DMT.SSN = Stage.SSN,
DMT.TPL_PAYOR = Stage.TPL_PAYOR, 
DMT.TPL_PRIM_NAME = Stage.TPL_PRIM_NAME, 
DMT.UPDATE_DATE = Stage.UPDATE_DATE;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: The log is filling up with what message?

Comment: @danny117 I think the OP means transaction log.

Comment: Correct - the transaction log is filling.  Since i am running with SSIS, i can't turn off logging.

Comment: It's hard to answer since you aren't saying what your constraints are. You can't do it in a single SQL statement, that's obvious but let's state it. So you need to code a few statements and a loop. You can do it in SSIS, or you can code a stored procedure, or of course a program in any language. You will need to keep track of the last key merged, and use a query in USING clause that selects 1,000 records from the last key, instead of the full table. To keep track of the last key, you can use a temporary table - or even delete merged rows from the source table if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to solve my problem:

```
num=1 ; while ((num < 100000)) ; do

MERGE INTO "SCHEMA"."PATIENT" AS DMT
USING "SCHEMA"."PATIENT_STAGE" AS Stage
update set 
DMT.MEMBER_ID = Stage.MEMBER_ID, 
DMT.ADDRESS1 = Stage.ADDRESS1, 
DMT.ADDRESS2 = Stage.ADDRESS2,
DMT.BENEFIT_ID = Stage.BENEFIT_ID, 
DMT.CITY = Stage.CITY, 
DMT.STATE = Stage.STATE,
DMT.CLIENT_CLIENT_ID = Stage.CLIENT_CLIENT_ID,
DMT.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID = Stage.CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID, 
DMT.CLIENT_GROUP_ID = Stage.CLIENT_GROUP_ID, 
DMT.DATE_OF_BIRTH = Stage.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
DMT.FIRST_NAME = Stage.FIRST_NAME, 
DMT.GENDER = Stage.GENDER, 
DMT.LAST_NAME = Stage.LAST_NAME,
DMT.MIDDLE_NAME = Stage.MIDDLE_NAME, 
DMT.PERSON_CODE = Stage.PERSON_CODE, 
DMT.SSN = Stage.SSN,
DMT.TPL_PAYOR = Stage.TPL_PAYOR, 
DMT.TPL_PRIM_NAME = Stage.TPL_PRIM_NAME, 
DMT.UPDATE_DATE = Stage.UPDATE_DATE(select........where <> fetch 1st 1000 rows only )
(num=num+1)
done
```

Comment: Can you ping the complete syntax